# Why moving an array definition into another class changes its item type to a complex object?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array in a `NotationConstant` class:

```
export class NotationConstant {
  public static readonly TIME_SIGNATURES: Array<number> = [2, 4];
}
```

Then I use it in another `SettingsDialogComponent` class:

```
private instantiateLists(): void {
  NotationConstant.TIME_SIGNATURES.forEach((timeSignature: number) => {
    console.log(timeSignature);
    this.timeSignatures.push({ 'id': timeSignature, 'name': String(timeSignature) });
  });
}
```

The console log statement show:

```
{id: 2, name: "2"}
{id: 4, name: "4"}
```

Where do these `id` property and `name` property come from ?

Another stranger thing.

I add the array definition in the `SettingsDialogComponent` class:

```
public static readonly TIME_SIGNATURES: Array<number> = [2, 4];
private instantiateLists(): void {
  SettingsDialogComponent.TIME_SIGNATURES.forEach((timeSignature: number) => {
    console.log(timeSignature);
    this.timeSignatures.push({ 'id': timeSignature, 'name': String(timeSignature) });
  });
}
```

Now the console log statement shows:

```
2
4
```

Why moving the array definition into another class changes its traversing ?

UPDATE: The issue is gone. The above source code is exactly the same. High chaparral.

Comment: Without an [mcve] I can only guess that you're mutating the original array and that gets by the compiler somehow. Or maybe you're not calling that method correctly. Or something else. It's not obvious what exactly is wrong from the code supplied here, since there could be multiple reasons.

Comment: The first set of code [works on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-e8qygm?file=index.ts)

Comment: Your stackblitz is exactly what I have, only yours works fine. I have to look deeper.